# How to disable or turn off notification come from system tray?

Tags: java, android, firebase, notifications

Hy everyone, I am developing an app that use firebase cloud messaging. In this app, I am using BroadcastReceiver instead of FirebaseMessagingService.

Here, BroadcastReceiver is used to save/store notification data in SQLite either in foreground/background or app is been killed.

The problem I am facing is, app is showing two notifications(i.e one from system tray and another from app). I don't want notification coming from system tray.

So, Is there any possible way to stop notification coming from system tray.

Comment: Hi have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

How are you sending the messages? The notification will only appear in the system tray if you are creating a `Notification` message (or mixed `Notification` and `Data` message) before sending.

The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) tell you which types of message goes to the tray and which are caught by the app's receiver, and some examples of `Notification` vs `Data` messages.

Example of `Notification` message

```
var message = {
  notification: {
    title: '$GOOG up 1.43% on the day',
    body: '$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.',
  },
  android: {
    ttl: 3600 * 1000,
    notification: {
      icon: 'stock_ticker_update',
      color: '#f45342',
    },
  }
}
```

Example of `Data` message

```
var message = {
  data: {
    title: '$GOOG up 1.43% on the day',
    body: '$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.',
  },
  android: {
    ttl: 3600 * 1000,
    notification: {
      icon: 'stock_ticker_update',
      color: '#f45342',
    },
  }
}
```

If you're using cloud functions to send messages, take a look at [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#resource:-message) reference document that outlines all parameters you can use to build messages.